# sudoku,recursive function solves half the puzzle

Tags: c++

I'm working on a Sudoku solver, and my program is having trouble recursing backwards when it has exhausted its outputs. 
I have four functions that do the check:
`scolumn`, `srow`, `sbox`. Each one will return false if the number already exists in the column row or box respectively.

```
bool sudoku::solve(int row, int column)
{
    if(column == 9)
    {
     column = 0; 
     row +=1;
    }
    if(puzzle[row][column] != 0)
    {
     solve(row, column + 1);
     return false;
    }
    else
    {
     for(int n = 0; n < 10; n ++)
     {
      if(srow(column, n) && scolumn(row,n) && sbox(row, column, n)
      {
       puzzle[row][column] = n;
       if(!solve(row, column + 1);
         table[row][column] = 0;
      }
     }
     puzzle[row][column] = 0;// if not commented out then infinite loop 
    }
   return false
}
```

the problem with it is that if its at 9 and there is no next choice, it will not backtrack correctly.

Comment: The puzzle complies. The problem is the recursion. If the current cell has no choices due to the srow sbox scolumn constraint. An the cell before it is a 9 it does not recurse. Back and edit the last cell correctly. Thus it will only solve half of a puzzle.

Comment: Yeah. I'm recursion isn't my strong suit so I'm not sure how to implement it correctly in this respect.  Also if I leave the puzzle assignment at the end of the function, it will go into an infinite loop.

Comment: You only ever return false. Aren't you supposed to be assigning the result of solve() to a return value. At least one case should be true.

Comment: `for(int n = 0` — really?

Comment: I think that a clever person might help you twist your code to make it work, but I suggest that a better approach would be for you to write a basic statement of your algorithm in words or pseudo code before presenting it as a code problem.   The problem is not that you have a problem with the code you posted, it is that you have not designed a recursive algorithm to solve the problem.   Can you type in how this is supposed to work, in English, or pseudocode?

Comment: Sorry that's also a typo but it, it should be one. I was messing around with the code. I also had a return true under 'if(!solve' but was trying something different

Comment: Write out how you would solve the puzzle manually. Step through your program manually and make sure it follows that same logic. As @acarlon pointed out, the fact that you never return true but are using the returned value in a conditional is one red flag; the fact that you aren't using the returned result at all in the other case is another.

Comment: another typo: `if(!solve(row, column + 1);`, remove extra `;`

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code, as people have observed in the comments.

This answer summarises some of them:

1) As @n.m. said, you should not be trying '0' as a valid choice in a cell.  That will be the cause of some infinite looping, no doubt.

2) As you have observed, you don't know how the recursion finishes.   The answer is that when you get to the last cell, and you find a value that works in it, you are supposed to return true.   This is what is supposed to break the for(n) loop: that loop is saying "try each number *until* the call of solve to the right of this cell *succeeds*'.   Success is measured by your routine returning true.

Since you try every number (n) in the current cell, no matter whether or not the call to the solve on its right works ... it's not going to work.

You'll know that you're more on the right track when:

- You can see the place in your code where you return true when you discover that you can put a number in the last cell (9,9)
- You can see how it is that you stop trying numbers (n=0..9) when the call to the right succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Given `int puzzle[9][9]`, and your `srow`, `scol`, and `sbox` functions:

```
bool sudoku::solve(int row, int column) //to solve entire puzzle, call with parameters 0 and 0
{
  int cell;

  //ignore all nonzero cells (zero = empty)
  while (row < 9 && puzzle[row][column] != 0)
  {
    column++;
    if (column == 9)
    {
      row++;
      column = 0;
    }
  }

  if (row == 9) return true; //puzzle is already solved

  //try values 1-9 inclusive.  If successful, then return true
  for (cell = 1; cell <= 9; cell++)
  {
    puzzle[row][column] = cell;
    if (srow(row) && 
        scol(column) && 
        sbox(row-row%3, column-column%3) &&
        solve(row, column)) //recursion!!
    {
        return true;
    }
  }
  //if no value works, reset the cell and return false.

  puzzle[row][column] = 0;
  return false;
}
```